# Error: Address already in use while binding socket with address but the port number is shown free by `netstat`

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I tried to bind my socket(server socket) at port number `8000`. It worked and did the job for me. At the end of the code I close the socket as well. The very next instant I run my code again and it shows me that the address is already in use. I have printed the meaning of error values `strerror(errno);` to see if my code working properly at each point. To check if the port is free I checked it using `netstat` but it shows that port number `8000` is free. It has happened with me a lot of times. Every time I then wait for a few more secs and then it starts working again. I am using c language. So what is he reason for this behavior by my OS.

After a few more secs I run the code and then it works.

```
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$ sudo ./a.out 
Socket Creation: Success
File open: Success
Socket Bind: Address already in use
Socket Listen: Address already in use
^C
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$ sudo netstat -lntp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1348/lighttpd   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      984/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1131/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1211/mysqld     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      984/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1131/cupsd      
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$ sudo ./a.out 
Socket Creation: Success
File open: Success
Socket Bind: Address already in use
Socket Listen: Address already in use
^C
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$
```

Comment: Do you also carefully close all connections that were made to the server while it was running?

Comment: Related question: [python - socket.error: \[Errno 48\] Address already in use - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071512/socket-error-errno-48-address-already-in-use) ■ More generally, this error message may also appear if some other running process is using the socket, refer to [c - Bind failed: Address already in use - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198834/bind-failed-address-already-in-use?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I've run into that same issue as well.  It's because you're closing your connection to the socket, but not the socket itself.  The socket can enter a TIME_WAIT state (to ensure all data has been transmitted, TCP guarantees delivery if possible) [and take up to 4 minutes to release](http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-4.html#ss4.2).

or, for a REALLY detailed/technical explanation, [check this link](http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-2.html#time_wait)

It's certainly annoying, but it's not a bug.  See the comment from @Vereb on this answer below on the use of `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: there is a possible solution on the page you linked. You can use the SO_REUSEADDR option for the socket. see setsockopt here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt

Answer (score 37):

I know its been a while since the question was asked but I was able to find a solution:

```
int sockfd;
int option = 1;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));
```

This set the socket able to be reused immediately.

I apologize if this is "wrong". I'm not very experienced with sockets

Comment: the quotes were more of an "if it works it's not wrong" kind of thing. I realize that probably not the preferred way and if anyone knows the "correct" way I would be interested to hear.

Comment: what does the 1 mean?

Comment: It was a while ago so if I'm wrong please correct me, but I believe that's used because when you want the socket to not linger that must be "non-zero". I couldn't find anything concrete but you can read more about it at : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.15/gtpc2/cpp_setsockopt.html

Comment: I think a listening server should set `SO_REUSEADDR` so this answer is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960219/why-not-using-so-reuseaddr-on-unix-tcp-ip-servers

Answer (score 27):

Try netstat like this: `netstat -ntp`, without the `-l`. It will show tcp connection in
`TIME_WAIT` state.

Answer (score 18):

As already said, your socket probably enter in `TIME_WAIT` state. This issue is well described by *Thomas A. Fine* [here](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html).

To summary, socket closing process follow diagram below:

[image: Socket closing process]

*Thomas* says:

> Looking at the diagram above, it is clear that `TIME_WAIT` can be
>   avoided if the remote end initiates the closure. So the server can
>   avoid problems by letting the client close first. The application
>   protocol must be designed so that the client knows when to close. The
>   server can safely close in response to an EOF from the client, however
>   it will also need to set a timeout when it is expecting an EOF in case
>   the client has left the network ungracefully. In many cases simply
>   waiting a few seconds before the server closes will be adequate.

Using `SO_REUSEADDR` is commonly suggested on internet, but *Thomas* add:

> Oddly, using `SO_REUSEADDR` can actually lead to more difficult "address
>   already in use" errors. `SO_REUSADDR` permits you to use a port that is
>   stuck in `TIME_WAIT`, but you still can not use that port to establish a
>   connection to the last place it connected to. What? Suppose I pick
>   local port 1010, and connect to foobar.com port 300, and then close
>   locally, leaving that port in `TIME_WAIT`. I can reuse local port 1010
>   right away to connect to anywhere except for `foobar.com` port 300.

Answer (score 10):

Just type

```
unlink [SOCKET NAME]
```

in the terminal, then the error should no longer exist.

Comment: That's for Unix-domain sockets. The question is about TCP sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Even icfantv's answer to this question is already perfect, I still have more findings in my test.

As a server socket in listening status, if it only in listening status, and even it accepts request and getting data from the client side, but without any data sending action. We still could restart the server at once after it's stopped. But if any data sending action happens in the server side to the client, the same service(same port) restart will have this error: (Address already in use).

I think this is caused by the TCP/IP design principles. When the server send the data back to client, it must ensure the data sending succeed, in order to do this, the OS(Linux) need monitor the connection even the server application closed this socket.
But I still believe kernel socket designer could improve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For AF_UNIX you can use call unlink (path); after close() socket in "server" app

Answer (score -4):

the error i received was:

```
cockpit.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Address already in use
```

the fix I discovered is:

1. I had to disable selinux
2. in /usr/lib/systemd/system/cockpit service i changed the
   line :

   ```
   #ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/remotectl certificate --ensure --user=root --group=cockpit-ws --selinux-type=etc_t
   ```

   to:

   ```
   #ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/remotectl certificate --ensure --user=root --group=cockpit-ws
   ```

so as you can see i took out the argument about selinux
then i ran:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start cockpit.service
```

then I browsed to:

I accepted the self-signed certificate and was
able to login successfully to cockpit and use it normally.

this is all on a fedora25 machine. the 9090 port had already
been added using `firewall-cmd`