# Clear ADDRINUSE

Tags: linux, sockets, bind

When I execute a program that uses bind() for second time in the same port, I obtain EADDRINUSE.

I don't want implement setsockopt() for reuse the socket. I want "clear" the used sockets used in used ports before execute my program.

More information: Linux OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Address already in use while binding socket with address but the port number is shown free by \`netstat\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106674/error-address-already-in-use-while-binding-socket-with-address-but-the-port-num)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you aren't cleaning up the socket(s) correctly and, so, the kernel will wait for further data to arrive (TIME_WAIT) and discard it (RST). If you do that successfully, you will be able to reuse the port immediately after with no need to "force" that through `setsockopt`.

Therefore, it is not possible to do but via `setsockopt` since you need to explicitly tell the kernel that such behavior has to be stopped.