# bind() failed: Address already in use

Tags: c, sockets, dns

I am implementing DNS server and DNS resolver and i am using socket programming in this. But i get error in function `bind()` as `bind()` failed and `sendto()` permission denied.

I had tried using different port numbers, also i am working as a root, but still it giving me same error.Please help me to solve those issues. Your answers are welcome. Thanks.

https://github.com/srijan/DNS-Server---Resolver/tree/c73a124a15f53eb985a4b4afc0dffedd432c8454

Comment: It usually means some other socket is open on the given port.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Address already in use while binding socket with address but the port number is shown free by \`netstat\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106674/error-address-already-in-use-while-binding-socket-with-address-but-the-port-num)

Comment: Can you post some actual code on where the error is occurring plus the error message?

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc That only applies to TCP sockets.  This is UDP.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/pallavihajare3/dns_implementation-1

Comment: Writing a resolver is _hard_ - be prepared for lots and lots of edge conditions

Comment: @dbush not true - it's possible to `bind()` UDP sockets, too.

Comment: how come the Git repo is 5 years old and you're just asking now?

Comment: @Alnitak I was referring to the dup specifally, which deals with TCP sockets in TIME_WAIT.  But yes, both TCP and UDP will fail to bind if another socket is open.

Comment: hello,dbush and Alnitak , i have shared my code on google site , i want IP address as a output , anyone could tell me ,what is going wrong in my code?Your suggestions are welcome.thanks.

Comment: @P.Hajare it rather looks like _someones else's_ code to me...

Comment: Yeah,but i want to use this code , i had understood working of dns , but while implementing i m facing problem.

Answer (score 2):

This error typically means some other socket in the system is open on the same port.

To see what other UDP sockets are open, run `netstat -anu` from the command line.  You'll get a list of IP/port pairings.  If you see one for port 53, that socket is conflicting with yours.  If you are able to run as root and also use the `-p` option, it will additionally tell you the process number that owns each socket.

Answer (score 1):

Run `Netstat -anob` with CLI in Windows.

```html
C:\Windows\System32>socat TCP-LISTEN:443,fork,reuseaddr TCP:localhost:22
2021/02/01 16:22:41 socat[11240] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:443}, 16): Address already in use

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -anob

Connexions actives

  Proto  Adresse locale         Adresse distante       État
  TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5676
 [sshd.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1244
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7396
 [vmware-hostd.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

`[vmware-hostd.exe]` is the process that listen instead of `[socat.exe]`.

In my case, I am using VMware Workstation 16 Pro and have disabled virtual machine sharing in Preferences, which is an deprecated option. All is now OK.

[WMware Workstation Server deprecated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHWe1.png)

Comment: Please explain what to look for in the output, with an example.